# Remove specific cookie from session python requests

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

Remove specific cookie from session python requests.

Only found

```
s.cookies.clear()
```

Would like to ONLY remove a specific cookie. e.g. s.cookies['basketid']

Answer (score 4):

From view of how cookie works on web, we should remove specific cookie in response, not from  request. Every time browser get a response from a server, it updates his cookie with cookie header in response.
So the answer is :

```
response.delete_cookie(cookie_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are creating this session:

```py
import requests
s = requests.session()
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set', params={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'but'})
```

Inspecting the cookie shows:

```py
s.cookies.keys()
```

```py
>> ['baz', 'foo']
```

Now, let's remove `foo` from the cookie:

```py
s.cookies.pop('foo', None)
```

This shows:

```py
s.cookies.keys()
```

```py
>> ['baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple delete should work, the syntax would be

```py
del s.cookies['basketid']
```

Comment: @B--rian  Why is this not an answer? It works and even uses the naming provided by the author. Other then the other "answers", this would even be a copy&paste answer for the original requestor

Comment: Well, it might be an answer, but it misses explanations that's why it got flagged for review, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer -- I deleted my comment, but agree with the flagger that it is too short.

Comment: @B--rian So adding an explanation like _because del is for deleting in the programming language you have chosen_ would make this a _correct_ answer?

Comment: I think so - I am just the reviewer of the flag and I voted for "looks like comment" rather "just delete" since it looked helpful. I already suggested an edit.